# Error de consulta Java a Prolog-Mysql en Fedora 22 (Netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql, prolog, jpl

He estado jugando con Java haciendo consultas a Prolog con la libreria JPL y me funciona, todo bien hasta ahí.

Luego realicé una conexión de Prolog a MySQL con ODBC y genial funcionaba. Luego tuve un problema con realizar consultas en Prolog conectando a MySQL mediante Java.

Cuando consulto mediante Java y ejecuto el archivo de Prolog intentando acceder a la base de datos, me da el siguiente error:

```
% comandos.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
%    library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 81 clauses
%    library(pairs) compiled into pairs 0.00 sec, 22 clauses
%   library(lists) compiled into lists 0.01 sec, 205 clauses
%  library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.01 sec, 246 clauses
ERROR: /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/library/odbc.pl:72:
    '$open_shared_object'/3: /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/lib/x86_64-</br>linux/odbc4pl.so: undefined symbol: PL_get_long
Warning: /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/library/odbc.pl:72:
    Goal (directive) failed: odbc:use_foreign_library(foreign(odbc4pl))
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_query/4 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_fetch/3 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_prepare/5 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_execute/3 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_close_statement/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_debug/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_connect/3 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_disconnect/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_get_connection/2 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_end_transaction/2 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_set_connection/2 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_free_statement/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure odbc:odbc_clone_statement/2 is not defined
% /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/library/odbc.pl compiled into odbc 0.02 sec, 324 clauses
ERROR: [Thread 1]: exception handler failed to define odbc:odbc_connect/3
   Exception: (4) odbc:odbc_connect('DB_prolog', _G3108, [user(root), password(*******), alias(dbprolog), open(once)]) ?
```

Estuve indagando. Vi un solo tutorial que estaba realizado en Windows y funcionaba, pero el S.O. que utilizo es Fedora22. No estoy seguro si es mi S.O. o el driver del ODBC a JLP.

Código de conexión en Prolog:

```
abrir_conexion:-
                odbc_connect('DB_prolog',_, [user(root), password('*******'), 
                alias(dbprolog), open(once)]).
```

Código de consulta Java:

```
String t1 = "consult('comandos.pl'),abrir_conexion.";
Query q1 = new Query(t1);
System.out.println(t1 + " " + (q1.hasSolution() ? "correcto" : "fallo"));
```

Comment: Hola @JeanPierre. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías agregar el fragmento de código que genera la conexión?

Comment: Código de conexión en Prolog.


abrir_conexion:-
  odbc_connect('DB_prolog',_,
      [user(root),
       password('*******'),
       alias(dbprolog),
       open(once)]).


Código de consulta Java


String t1 = "consult('comandos.pl'),abrir_conexion.";
        Query q1 = new Query(t1);
        System.out.println(t1 + " " + (q1.hasSolution() ? "correcto" : "fallo"));

Comment: @JeanPierreSotoChirinos edita tu pregunta para incorporar el extracto de código, así apenas es legible.

Comment: `ERROR: /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/library/odbc.pl:72:
    '$open_shared_object'/3: /usr/lib64/swipl-6.6.6/lib/x86_64- linux/odbc4pl.so: undefined symbol: PL_get_long`

Este es el problema que desencadena el resto, es un error muy común en las librerías de Prolog, no se aun. No pude resolverlo, pero según los foros se utiliza el LD_PRELOAD, bueno busque como usarlo pero me resulta confuso su uso.

Comment: Espero esto te ayude: https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/issues/10